# Can't ping remote VPS host via VPN

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I have a remote VPS running OpenVPN server at some ip (`my.vps.host.ip`). Also I have Raspberry Pi router (RaspPI) running OpenVPN client that routes all traffic connected to it via `wlan0` to that OpenVPN server.
The problem is: from any device connected to Raspbery Pi router via `wlan0`, I can ping any valid IP address except `my.vps.host.ip`. Thus, I can't connect to the VPS using `ssh`.

```
Kernel IP routing table (RaspPI)
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
my.vps.host.ip  192.168.31.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.17.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.31.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Tracing route from device connected via VPN gives the following:

```
traceroute to my.vps.host.ip, 64 hops max
  1   192.168.17.1  0,859ms  0,928ms  0,845ms 
  2   *  *  *
```

From RaspPI itself `my.vps.host.ip` can be pinged. The firewalls on both RaspPI and VPS are disabled.
How can I make `my.vps.host.ip` accessible for VPN clients?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the above problem is still unknown to me, but a workaround was found: routing all traffic from `wlan0` to `my.vps.host.ip` and vice versa directly via `eth0` gateway.
Following lines added to `iptables` solved the problem:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -d my.vps.host.ip -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -s my.vps.host.ip -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```